# Progress during a file saving

Tags: c++, file, qt, progress-bar, save

I have a large image that I have to save with `image.save(fichier)`. How could I possibly display a progressbar of the saving state?

This may be a trivial question but I really don't how to do this as it's a one-line command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can't using the built in image save. 
You could estimate the save time (know size of image, guess mb/s),  and put up a progress bar and just use a timer to update it.

Or you can have a progress bar  that just runs quickly to the end and restarts to show some activity but not the actual progress.

edit: if you really must have a progress you could 'save' the image data in memory and then write the memory to disk a block at a time updating the progress.

```
 QImage image;
 QByteArray bytes;
 QBuffer buffer(&bytes);
 buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
 image.save(&buffer, "PNG"); // writes image into buffer in PNG format
```

Then write the buffer to disk

Comment: The problem is that the program will run on very different machines so I'd prefer not to make any guess, besides I still don't see how I could implement this. How can I update anything while the `image.save(fichier)` statement is being executed?

Comment: The timer signal/slot will still execute while in a save task. Timers are a cheap and easy way to do multitasking. You could also check the image file size in the timer slot - but depending on the OS it may allocate the full size at the start of the save and then fill it

Answer (score 1):

You can run `QImage::save()` in another thread, while the main thread shows the progressbar, updating its progress value every second with expected_size/current_size. You can get current size with `QFile::size()`

Comment: I have just one question regarding this solution, how can I get the expected size of the file? All I know is the number of pixel, but I don't know how to translate this into a number of bites especially with the quality factor...